# With google apps script how can I know in a function if it's called by user or trigered?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I create a function "myFunction" in a google spreadsheet which could be called by user or run by Time-driven trigger.
I want to display a message if it's user runs the function or log a message if it's the running by trigger.

At the moment I create this "myFunction" with a parameter (userCall as boolean) and create two others functions :

```
function createHistoUser() {
  createHisto(true);
};

function createHistoTrigger() {
  createHisto(false);
};

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Create Histo', 'createHistoUser')
    .addToUi();
};
```

It's not very clean I think.
If there is a method to know if it's a user calling or a triggered calling I can delete the 2 functions.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could look for the triggers event object

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The code in the question doesn't include a function named `myFunction`. Are you referring to `createHisto` function?